# Tell PDF Viewer/Adobe Reader to go to page on OS X

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to make an integrated presentation for my students.

System: OS X Lion 10.7

For that I need to show a foreground window running a 3D presentation which is remotely controlled by a command line on another screen.

Besides it I would like to show a small set of PDF slides behind it.

I need some way of "remote controlling" the **backgrounded** PDF Viewer (Adobe Reader or PDFView) to accept simple commands like

- Go to Page `x` (ideally)
- Go to first page (`home button`)
- Go to next page (`arrow down`, `arrow right`, `page down` or `scroll down` will all do)

I prefer to run the PDF in Adobe Reader fullscreen mode (allows me to background it and overlay another window on top, but PDFView could do too.

I have tried various Applescripts (run with `osascript`), but with no success:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Reader"
        tell window "starkdemo.pdf" to key code 125
    end tell
end tell
```

sends key down to my terminal

```
tell application "/Applications/Adobe Reader.app"
    tell active pane of active window
        large scroll down 1
    end tell
end tell
```

gives me an error `63:69: script error: Expected end of line but found class name. (-2741)`

Comment: Being an Apple product, Preview probably has more Applescript hooks than the other apps.

Comment: @craig65535 Unfortunately being an Apple product Preview.app knows how to make everything else go away on my screen when put into Fullscreen/Slideshow mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
activate application "Adobe Reader"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Reader"
        click menu item "Full Screen Mode" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
        delay 2
        key code 125
        delay 2
        keystroke space
        delay 2
    end tell
end tell
```

Or try this with Acrobat Pro

```
tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
    tell PDF Window 1
        read page down
    end tell
end tell
```

Or

```
tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
    tell PDF Window 1
        goto page 3
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Yeah, you have kind of missed the point. `activate application "Adobe Reader"` will bring it into foreground. I want to keep it's windows behind my 3D viewer. Chain activating application will give me very nasty flickering in my presentation which I can live without.

Comment: Download Acrobat Pro and try the second script.  Trial version: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=acrobat_pro&loc=en

Comment: This works, with errors, but it works. Where did you find the documentation for this API? Any chance there is a `goto #page` call?

Comment: Once you have Acrobat Pro installed, use File --> Open Dictionary from AppleScript Editor to find a complete list of commands.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that the free Viewer [Skim](http://sourceforge.net/projects/skim-app/) has extensive AppleScript scripting http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/skim-app/index.php?title=AppleScript

It also have the fullscreen view that I like. So I will be using this in the future. Also the applescript command is just one line:

```
tell document "starkdemo.pdf" of application "Skim" to go to page 7
```